# QMainWindow freezes upon watchdog.start(), how to make them work simultaneously?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, python-watchdog

I have an application which I wanted to add an 'automode' to.

```
def start_stop_automode(self):
    self.set_auto()

   if not self.auto_mode_btn.isChecked() and self.observer.is_alive():
       self.observer.stop()
       self.observer.join()
       return
   else:
       self.observer.start()
       while True:
          try:
             time.sleep(1)
          except KeyboardInterrupt:
             self.observer.stop()
             self.observer.join()
```

It calls a slot which starts the `watchdog` `FileSystemEventHandler` class which in turn executes some functions on the file that triggered the `watchdog` `event`.

```
class Event(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_created(self, event):   

    input_path = event.src_path
    if input_path.endswith('_1.CSV'):

        if self.file_creation_finished(input_path):
            file = os.path.split(input_path)[-1].rstrip('.CSV')
            file = file.split('_')[0]
            self.exec_funk(order=file)
```

Through debugg i saw that the code inside the `FileSystemEventHandler` class is performed correctly, except the missing functionality of the `QMainWindow` actually being operational while the `watchdog` is running.
How do i accomodate them both?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i realize now how simple the solution was, just remove the `while loop` and you can work with the `QMainWindow`.